# Can't create table on phpmyadmin #1067 error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I can't create a table on my phpmyadmin... date is alway invalid... I already used TIMESTAMP and DATETIME datatype.. but still got some errors...
mysql version: 5.7.14 and im using wamp
[image]

Comment: u added the data type as timestamp, if you addthe Type as Date will work fine with default Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible the strict mode and NO_ZERO_DATE are enabled. This pair produces an error on zero dates.

Check the SQL_MODE and have a look at this page - [NO_ZERO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date)

Comment: how can i disable the no_zero_date?

Comment: There is a how-to, see `Setting the SQL Mode` in link from answer.

Comment: thanks @Devart.. I just uncomment the sql-mode="" to disable the restriction

Answer (score 1):

Put default TimeStamp to:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 1):

Your default for `date_crated` value is incorrect.

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

> The range for TIMESTAMP values is '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' to
>   '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999'

Typically, you should set the default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

---

### IMPORTANT NOTE

This solution will only work until January 19, 2038, at 3:14:07 AM. Which is, by the time of writing this answer, about 21 years away. So to future programmers, if MySQL does not update/fix this limitation, you will have a problem and must find a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Your `date_created` column has type `timestamp` and you are giving `0000-00-00 00:00` as default value,  which is incorrect for timestamp, you can select `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for this column.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no solution to this problem. It does not matter what I do, if I use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, or '1970....', a normal valid date, NULL, just nothing, or whatever,
and even if I run:

```
SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

(that command actually succeeds)

.. but it is still error #1067. Nothing helps.

I move over to Ubuntu now, where I have no problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I finally fixed it also in phpMyAdmin!

Just run from the SQL panel in phpMyAdmin:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

In my case, I had NO_ZERO_DATE here.

I then set this to exactly what I use on my Ubuntu system:

```
set global sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Now it all works using '0000-00-00 00:00' as default value